# How to display an error message if the browser's pop up blocker has been enabled

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing a site. in that site on clicking a button, it should redirect to the next page. My question is while clicking the button, it should check whether the browser's pop up blocker has been enabled or not. If it is enabled, then i should display an error message saying that the pop up has been blocked. Or else should move on to next page. Is it possible through the coding?? Please help me soon

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. What does the pop up do ? Why do you need a popup to redirect to the next page ?

Also, if the pop-up is blocked, the browser should tell it himself and your users will be notified.

Answer (score 2):

try like this. it will return true or false. for blockd pop up.

```
function isPopupBlocked()
{
 var oWin = window.open("UrltoOpen","yourName","width=0,height=0,top=5000,left=5000");
        if (oWin==null || typeof(oWin)=="undefined") {
            return true;
        } else {
            oWin.close();
            return false;
        }
}
```

Comment: Why do `oWin==null || typeof(oWin)=="undefined"` when you could do `!oWin`?

Answer (score 0):

TO DETECT IF POPUP IS BLOCKED:

```
var newWin = window.open(url);             

if(!newWin || newWin.closed || typeof newWin.closed=='undefined') 
{ 
   //POPUP BLOCKED
}
```

Comment: Pop up being blocked and javascript disabled, i believe are two different things ! !

Comment: I do not see the value in `typeof newWin.closed=='undefined'` when there is already `!newWin`